# Container divided by frictionless adiabatic wall: reversible or irreversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, reversibility, adiabatic

I have encountered an issue in the following physical situation. Consider a rigid, thermally insulated container divided by a barrier parallel to its base into two parts, left and right, each containing $n$ moles of the same (ideal) gas. The partition prevents the exchange of particles and heat between the two parts. Initially, the position of the wall is locked; the system is at equilibrium with the two parts at the same volume $V_{\text{left,initial}} = V_{\text{right,initial}}$, but different temperatures $T_{\text{left,initial}} > T_{\text{right,initial}}$. At a certain instant, the moving wall is left free to slide without friction and the system, after a rapid transformation, reaches a new equilibrium condition.
How to approach this situation? **Is the transformation that takes place reversible or irreversible?**

If we treat the current process as reversible, we would have to exert external force (and work) to manually control the moving barrier so that the process is quasi-statically and takes place relatively slowly. This is not the case (the process is spontaneous and rapid).

If we treat the current process as irreversible, the volume would have to change at a speed comparable with the speed of sound in the gas. Since the speed of sound is hundreds of metres per second the partition would have to move at hundreds of metres per second for the process to deviate significantly from approximately reversible (as @JohnRennie notes and states). Is this really possible?

So, what is the final answer as to the correct assumption to carry out?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150392/discussion-on-question-by-bml-container-divided-by-frictionless-adiabatic-wall); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.